# I am not able to find relevent data using soup.findAll() while doing webscraping using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data(names,ages,teams) from this website-**https://sofifa.com/players?offset=0**.
While I was trying to find the relevent data using soup.findAll(), I am getting an **empty list**.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import re
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    k=[]
    url="https://sofifa.com/players?offset=0"
    resp=requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(resp.content,'lxml')
    for omk in soup.find_all('><div class="bp3-text-overflow-ellipsis">'):
      k.append(str(omk))
    print(k)
```

I read some answers which had mentioned about tags and class but I don't know about these are.

Answer (score 1):

According to your question, here is an example of working solution:

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

k = []
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36'}

url = "https://sofifa.com/players?offset=0"
resp = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'lxml')
for omk in soup.select('table.table.table-hover.persist-area tbody tr'):
    name = omk.select_one('td.col-name a:nth-child(1) div').get_text(strip=True)
    print(name)
```

Output:

```
M. Sarr
É. Mendy
P. Daka
F. Wirtz
J. Timber        
C. De Ketelaere  
Cristiano Ronaldo
D. Maldini       
J. Bellingham    
Lucas Paquetá    
Gavi
Antony
A. Spörle        
K. Adeyemi       
E. Haaland       
D. Kamada     
M. Salah      
N. Madueke    
A. Tchouaméni 
M. Greenwood  
M. Lacroix    
R. Gravenberch
Pedri
J. Gvardiol   
N. Lang
Raphinha
A. Hložek
J. Musiala
F. Chiesa
L. Messi
B. Brereton Díaz
R. Cherki
D. Vlahović
Ansu Fati
Pedro Benito
G. Raspadori
Yeremy Pino
Y. Tielemans
K. Mbappé
E. Camavinga
D. Scarlett
A. Bastoni
J. Sancho
T. Hernández
A. Davies
J. Koundé
A. Saint-Maximin
H. Elliott
S. Tonali
A. Broja
A. Isak
M. Vandevoordt
P. Foden
F. Kessié
J. Doku
E. Tapsoba
K. Mitoma
Luiz Felipe
Nuno Mendes
S. Dest
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues with your code snippet.

The first is that you need to specify an HTML parser when instantiating your `BeautifulSoup` instance:

```py
soup=BeautifulSoup(resp.content,'html.parser')
```

Then, when searching for a `div` element with a class of `bp3-text-overflow-ellipsis`, the proper syntax is the following:

```py
soup.find_all("div", class_="bp3-text-overflow-ellipsis")
```

Here is the documentation related to `find_all`: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all

Answer (score 0):

Your way of using `.find_all()` is incorrect. For correct usage refer the docs [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find).

This is how you need to do.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="https://sofifa.com/players?offset=0"
resp=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(resp.content,'lxml')

t = soup.find('tbody', class_='list')
items = []
for i in t.find_all('tr'):
    name = i.find('td', class_='col-name').find('a', class_='tooltip').text.strip()
    age = i.find('td', class_='col-ae').text.strip()
    team = i.find_all('td', class_='col-name')[-1].find('a').text.strip()
    items.append([name, age, team])

df = pd.DataFrame(items,columns=['Name', 'Age', 'Team'])
print(df)
```

```
                 Name Age                    Team
0          C. Musonda  24                 Chelsea
1          J. Álvarez  21             River Plate
2           Ansu Fati  18            FC Barcelona
3       Arthur Cabral  23           FC Basel 1893
4      A. Schjelderup  17         FC Nordsjælland
5           J. Correa  26                   Inter
6            F. Wirtz  18     Bayer 04 Leverkusen
.
.
.
58            A. Isak  21           Real Sociedad
59        Eric García  20            FC Barcelona
```